# MeteorJS, coffeescript files not loaded on the clientside

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'm trying to use coffeescript for my client-side code in Meteor, but it doesn't seem to work..

I've created `client/views/welcome/index.coffee` with the following content:

```
console.log 'this is welcome index'
```

But the console isn't logging anything and I don't see the file being loaded at the client.

Comment: Do you have the coffeescript package running? you can run `meteor list --using` to print a list in the terminal

Comment: Hah! Googling for "meteor coffeescript" got me right to the coffeescript part, without me knowing I'm on the Packages page.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command to add the coffeescript package to Meteor, which will enable the transpiling of coffeescript source:

```
meteor add coffeescript
```

Otherwise, coffeescript files will be silently ignored (there was a [suggestion to improve this behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/uJh_Y64NkYM)). For now, you can make sure the package is added by checking for it in `.meteor/packages`.

Comment: I've added `alethes:pages` package which says it installed coffeescript as well ("coffeescript   added, version 1.0.6") but it still didn't work until I added coffeescript package manually.

Comment: That only gives access to coffeescript for the code inside that package; you still have to add it to your app itself.